# VBA autofill down using a named range as destination

Tags: excel, vba

Very simple question - exactly as the title says. I have searched thoroughly and can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a formula in range("D3").  I have a named range called "copyrange", which is a single cell in column D, below D3. I want to autofill D3 down to all the cells down to and including "copyrange".

I presume it's some variant of:

ws.Range("D3").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("D3:copyrange"), Type:=xlFillDefault

but I can't work out the syntax.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `ws.Range("D3",range("copyrange"))`

Comment: Hi Scott - many thanks for the answer, but that doesn't work - generates an application-defined or object-defined error as before:

ws.Range("D3").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("D3", Range("copyrange")), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: Are you sure that `copyrange` is a named range and not range object variable?  They are two different things and are handled differently.

Comment: @Scott - I suspect it may be a range object variable.  That sounds like a plausible explanation - thanks.  I will investigate.

Comment: Then `ws.Range("D3",copyrange)`

Comment: Make sure that copyrange is on the same sheet as ws

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Scott.  It was the same sheet.  I ended up using an alternative method due to this taking too long but will revisit with your tips.